# How can I get chart to update with filter(ListCollectionView) in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, filter

I'm able to apply filter to an ObservableCollection and it applies to a listbox and a datagrid that I have in the XAML-code, but the chart that I have doesn't update. All have the same DataContext.

XAML-code:

```
        <ListBox Name="lst" ItemsSource="{Binding Measurements}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding sDate}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Place}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Consumtion}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>



                <tk:Chart Margin="0,20,0,0" Name="chart" Title="{Binding ElementName=place, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Height="279">
                    <tk:ColumnSeries IndependentValuePath="sDate" DependentValuePath="Consumtion" Title="Consumtion" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></tk:ColumnSeries>
                    <tk:Chart.Axes>
                        <tk:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" Title="Personer"></tk:CategoryAxis>
                        <tk:CategoryAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Förbrukning (kWh)"></tk:CategoryAxis>
                    </tk:Chart.Axes>
                </tk:Chart>



            <DataGrid Margin="0,20,0,0" Name="grid"></DataGrid>
```

C# code:

```
        DataContext = vm;
        chart.DataContext = vm.Measurements;            
        grid.ItemsSource = vm.Measurements;
```

I'm applying the filter by pressing a button and the listbox and the gridview updates but not the chart, is there a way to also update the chart?